# Trying to find a large string between a start point and end point using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a big chunk of text that I'm checking for a specific pattern, which looks essentially like this:

```
     unique_options_search = new Set([
            "updates_EO_LTB",
            "us_history",
            "uslegacy",

etc., etc., etc.

        ]);

      $input.typeahead({
        source: [...unique_options_search],
        autoSelect: false,
        afterSelect: function(value)
```

My text variable is named `'html_page'` and my start and end points look like this:

```
start = "new Set(["
end = "]);"
```

I thought I could find what I want with this one-liner:

```
r = re.findall("start(.+?)end",html_page,re.MULTILINE)
```

However, it's not returning anything at all.  What is wrong here?  I saw other examples online that worked fine.

Comment: `start` and `end` in the text literally match the words “start” and “end”, not the variables. Use `format()` to add the variables into the string.

Comment: @EthanK or an [f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339121/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-f-string).

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, but `format` is better.

Comment: @EthanK why is `format` better? OP could just say `f"{start}(.+?){end}"` (as long as they're first escaped the values of start and end).

Comment: @PeterWood, Oh yeah, sorry. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

1. As mentioned by @EthanK in comments, `"start(.+?)end"` in Python is a string which describes regex which literally matches `start`, then something, and then literally matches `end`. Variables `start` and `end` do not matter here at all.
   You've probably meant to write `start + "(.+?)" + end` here instead.
2. `.` in Python does not match newlines. `re.MULTILINE` does not matter here, it only changes behavior of `^` and `$` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)). You should use `re.DOTALL` instead (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)).
3. Values of `start` and `end` include characters with special meaning in regex (e.g. `(` and `[`). You have to make sure they're not treated specially. You can either escape them manually with the right number of `\` or simply delegate that work to [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to get regular expression which literally matches what you need.

Combining all that together:

```
import re
html_page = """
     unique_options_search = new Set([
            "oecd_updates_EO_LTB",
            "us_history",
            "us_legacy",

etc., etc., etc.

        ]);

      $input.typeahead({
        source: [...unique_options_search],
        autoSelect: false,
        afterSelect: function(value) 
"""

start = "new Set(["
end = "]);"
# r = re.findall("start(.+?)end",html_page,re.MULTILINE)  # Old version
r = re.findall(re.escape(start) + "(.+?)" + re.escape(end), html_page, re.DOTALL)  # New version
print(r)
```

Comment: For number 3: you can use a raw string. Begin the string like this for the regexp: `r'myMatchThing...'` with a `r''` to escape. Raw strings a better to use because they are built in to python.

Comment: @EthanK raw strings do not help with no. 3. Parsing of regular expression happens inside `re` library, and `r"hello(["` is exactly the same as `"hello(["` (`r` only changes meaning of stuff like `\n`, is which processed by Python parser). See [example](https://ideone.com/BvdhoV)

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. I got confused because I always add a raw string to my regexps. I didn’t see one so I thought one was needed.