# How to make python printf return this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, printf, string.format

I need `print(f"" + xx)` to output `text aaa` but it outputs `{x}` how could i make this work?

I have tried with printf and .format but couln't make any of those to work

```py
x = "aa"
xx = "text {x}"
x = "aaa"
print(f"" + xx)
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish with that code.

Comment: The `xx` needs to be inside a `f" ... "` block otherwise it won't be interpolated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string into an f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339121/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-f-string)

Comment: what is your python version ? It won't work if it is lesser 3.6. Since formatted string literals were added in python 3.6. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `str.format`, not an f-string.

```
xx = "text {x}"
x = "aaa"
print(xx.format(x=x))  # -> text aaa
```

Or without passing `x` explicitly:

```
print(xx.format(**locals()))  # -> text aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the variable you are trying to print within `f"{}"`:

```
x = "aa"
xx = "{x}"
x = "aaa"
print(f"{x}")
```

Otherwise, `xx` is literally `"{x}"` and is not expanded.