# Apply f-string interpolation to a string

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

Is there a way to achieve applying f-strings interpolation dynamically on a string?

For example given the string `a = '{len([1])}'`

`a.interpolate()` to give `'1'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string into an f-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339121/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-f-string)

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/can-i-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings#comment72134685_42497625) explains succinctly why this isn't exactly possible

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 a = f'{len([1])}'
 print(a)
 #1
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP wants

Comment: How is that the opposite? please explain

Comment: OP wants dynamic, but this is static. OP wants `a == '{len([1])}'`, but in your code `a == '1'`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for that