# Read curly braces yaml to python

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

i'm setting some parameters in `testing.yaml`

```
a :
    one : 
        file_name : 10/a_one 10.xlsx
        index_col : 0
```

which i can read in python through the script below with no problem

```
with open('testing.yaml') as f:
    data = ruamel.yaml.load(f, Loader=ruamel.yaml.Loader)
print(f"{data['a']['one']['file_name']}")
```

the output is `10/a_one 10.xlsx`. i will save a `dataframe` from this input using `pd.read_excel()`. however, if i want to include formattable strings which are changed from within python, i get an error. for example: say i want to be able to change the `10` in python, i edit `testing.yaml`

```
a :
    one : 
        file_name : {month}/a_one {month}.xlsx
        index_col : 0
```

and the script in python would then say

```
month = 10
with open('testing.yaml') as f:
    data = ruamel.yaml.load(f, Loader=ruamel.yaml.Loader)
print(f"{data['a']['one']['file_name']}")
```

i expect the output to be `10/a_one 10.xlsx` again here, can i achieve this somehow? the reason i don't want to make all changes within in the YAML-file directly, is because that some formatting information (in this case `month = 10`) is coming from another excel-file which is read within python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that f-strings are indeed a way of executing *arbitrary* code. As can be read in the answer to this question [How do I convert a string into an f-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339121/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-f-string)

So it is advisable *not* to try to use f-strings for formatting external data. Instead, try to stick to the good old `string.format` method:

```py
print(data['a']['one']['file_name'].format(month=month))
```

In your yaml you need to put the curly-braces into a string:

```yaml
a :
    one : 
        file_name : "{month}/a_one {month}.xlsx"
        index_col : 0
```

Otherwise you will get a Parser error like this:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "testing.yaml", line 3, column 9
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "testing.yaml", line 3, column 28
```

With the fixed yaml file above python statement produces the desired output:

```
10/a_one 10.xlsx
```

Comment: oh wow, i thought `f"{var}"` was exactly the same as `(var).format(var)`. thanks for the information and solution!