# Print out one cell in sqlite as f string

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to print out a cell in sqlite as f string, to use it outside of database. I'm get this printout when program is running:

> Please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation method' +
> Invalid input: 'NoneType' object is not iterable please enter a new number

I have been trying with different methods without success, I cannot convert None to f string.

My program:

```
class GameTracking:
    def __init__(self):
        self.view_name()

    def view(self):
        for row in database_input.view():
            extracted_name = print(type(row))
            print(str(f"Hey {extracted_name} selected correct"))
            print(str(extracted_name.__str__()))
                  
    def view_name(self):
        """
        Displaying name of player as f string
        """
        self.view() # display name as f string in print statement maybe fetch name for another file -> tracking of name and score
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform string to f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757222/transform-string-to-f-string)

Comment: Please include your entire error message and traceback.

Comment: Note that in this line `extracted_name = print(type(row))` the print function returns `None` and it gets assigned to `extracted_name`.  That said, a value of `None` will work just fine with your f-string.

Comment: Im only get this printout:
please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation method' +
<class 'str'>
Hey None selected correct
None

program seems does not crash

Comment: @Hawkeye: Please edit your question with enough information to duplicate your error. One thing I notice is your comment doesn't match your question.  Your question has "Invalid input: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" but your comment has "Invalid input: unbound method str.format() needs an argument".

Comment: Just a as extra Info I has saved Tg  -> my playername to database and

Comment: @StevenRumbalski sorry for that it was a copy error mistake, its correct now

Comment: Your question in its current form does not have enough information to be answerable and as such I am voting to close it. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I agree with you, I need to rethink of my question to solve this, Im newbie here, thanks for the link to about how ask question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem :-)

Since this player name was imported from another a file and some part was not included from start when I wrote the question, due to I was thinking it was not needed.

Here is my solution :-) It was only needed to get the "return rows" to printout file to make it to work. :-)

From database file:

```
def view(self):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT first_name FROM book ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    rows = self.cur.fetchone()
    return rows
```

From printout file:

```
from UserAccoutDetailsBackEndOOP import Database_input
import GameTrackingBackEndOOP as rows
database_input = Database_input("accountdetails.db")
view = Database_input

class GameTracking:
def __init__(self):
    self.view_name()

def view(self):
    extracted_name = rows 
    for extracted_name in database_input.view():
        print (str(f"Hey {extracted_name} selected correct"))
           
def view_name(self):
    """
    Displaying name of player as f string
    """
    self.view() # display name as f string in print statement maybe fetch name for another file -> tracking of name and score
```

And result is: (TG is playername from sqlite database)

```
  please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 
 'change calculation method' +
  Hey Tg selected correct
```